# Get element from JQuery object array

Tags: jquery

See my code:

```
var ths = $("#my_table table th");
if (ths.length > 1) {
    var $th = ths[1]; // tried here plain 'var th' - still got error 
    th.find('#map_column_element_id'); // error here!
}
```

I get array of JQuery objects. Then I try to manage the second element as JQuery object. When I issue

```
th.find(...)
```

I get **TypeError: th.find is not a function**. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why would you need to `find` an element by its `id`? `id`s should be unique on the page so `$("#map_column_element_id")` should be fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're getting the native JS DOM element, which doesn't have a `find()` method. Use `eq()`, or rewrap the element with `$(ths[1])`.

I'd use `eq()`, like so:

```
var ths = $("#my_table table th");
if (ths.length > 1) {
    var $th = ths.eq(1);
    $th.find('#map_column_element_id');
}
```

Also agree with Andrew in the comment, an ID is unique, and there should be no need to `find()` it, simply doing `$('#map_column_element_id')` should suffice.